# Installations: Passwords do not match

Tags: installation

Installation:

Downloaded WUBI from Ubuntu site today; therefore, I presume this is the latest version of WUBI.  The first screen requires a user name and password.  I enter both and receive an error message :

> "Passwords do not match."

The screen does not have a field to enter a 'verify' password.  I've never had Ubuntu installed on this machine.  To the best of my knowledge I have no passwords for anyone stored on this machine.  To what is this comparison being made and, more importantly, how do I bypass this glitch and get on with the installation?

I'd very much appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: you may need to scroll down to see the verify field.

Answer (score 1):

This password will become the password of the new user in the new Ubuntu installation. If is not password of any old Ubuntu installation.

Provide a username and also type a password twice in the two separate field there. The username is your Login name in new Ubuntu and password is that user's password.